# Error compiling for board esp32 Dev Module

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32, arduinojson

## **Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev module.**

Hello!
I'm here seeking your assistance please.
I have been working with arduino and esp32 module for posting some data to a dedicated platform.
However, upon modifying the data to json supported format as shown below the error started to emerge.

```
//----------------------------------------GET HTTP Request
  // Prepare POST request data
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
  doc["dht_sensor_API_KEY"] = apiKeyValue;
  doc["temperature"] = temperature;
  doc["humidity"] = humidity;

  // Serialize data to JSON
  serializeJson(doc, httpRequestData);
    
  // Send POST request
  httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
```

I'm working on a personal project that involves sending DHT sensor data toa  dedicated hosted platform with telemetry data packaged in JSON format using `DynamicJsonDocument`.as shown in my actual code snippet below

```
#include <ESP_WiFiManager.h>
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
//----------------------------------------Support libraries and sensor parameters.
#ifdef ESP32
  #include <WiFi.h>
  #include <HTTPClient.h>
  #include <WebServer.h>
  #include <ESPmDNS.h>
//  #include <analogWrite.h>
#else
//  #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//  #include <WiFiClient.h>
//  #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
//  #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
//  #include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#endif
#include <Arduino_JSON.h>
#define ON_Board_LED 2
#define DHT_PIN 27
#define DHT_SENSOR_TYPE DHT11
DHT dht_sensor(DHT_PIN, DHT_SENSOR_TYPE);
//----------------------------------------

/*
  SEND DHT DATA TO THE SERVER BASED ON 
  PROJECT API_KEY
  06-02-023
*/

//----------------------------------------Network credentials definition.
const char* ssid = ""; //--> Your wifi name or SSID.
const char* password = ""; //--> Your wifi PASSWORD.
String apiKeyValue = "";
//const char* server_url = "http://192.168.1.111/api/led_state_control";
const char* server_url = "";
//----------------------------------------


//----------------------------------------Control variables.
int temperature;
int humidity;
int humid_threshold;
int temp_threshold;
String payload;
WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;
String httpRequestData= "0";
int httpResponseCode= 0;
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;
//----------------------------------------


void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  pinMode(ON_Board_LED,OUTPUT);     //--> On Board LED port Direction output
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH); //--> Turn off Led On Board

  Serial.print("Connecting.");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    //----------------------------------------Make the On Board Flashing LED on the process of connecting to the wifi router.
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, HIGH);
    delay(250);
    //----------------------------------------
  }
  //----------------------------------------
  digitalWrite(ON_Board_LED, LOW); //--> Turn off the On Board LED when it is connected to the wifi router.
  //----------------------------------------If successfully connected to the wifi router, the IP Address that will be visited is displayed in the serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Successfully connected to : ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  
  dht_sensor.begin(); // initialize the DHT sensor
  //----------------------------------------

  Serial.println("Server started");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("connecting...");

  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  
  // Initialize http protocol
  http.begin(client, server_url);

  // take sensor readings
  humidity  = dht_sensor.readHumidity();
  temperature = dht_sensor.readTemperature();


  // check whether the reading is successful or not
  if ( isnan(humidity) || isnan(temperature)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
    return;
  }

  //  get server response from handler fn
  String dht_data = httpGETRequest(server_url);

  // decode response
  JSONVar json_res_data = JSON.parse(dht_data);

  // validate response type
  if(JSON.typeof(json_res_data) == "undefined"){
    Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
    return;
  }

  // decode actual dht data
  humidity = (const int)(json_res_data["humidity"]);
  temperature = (const int)(json_res_data["temperature"]);
  humid_threshold = (const int)(json_res_data["humid_threshold"]);
  temp_threshold = (const int)(json_res_data["temp_threshold"]);
  
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Temp: " + String(temperature));
  Serial.println("Humidity: " + String(humidity));
  Serial.println("Temp threshold: " + String(temp_threshold));
  Serial.println("Humid threshold: " + String(humid_threshold));

  delay(60000);

}
  //  GET request function
String httpGETRequest(const char* serverName) {
  
  //Specify content-type header
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   

  //----------------------------------------GET HTTP Request
  // Prepare POST request data
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
  doc["dht_sensor_API_KEY"] = apiKeyValue;
  doc["temperature"] = temperature;
  doc["humidity"] = humidity;

  // Serialize data to JSON
  serializeJson(doc, httpRequestData);
    
  // Send POST request
  httpResponseCode = http.POST(httpRequestData);
  //----------------------------------------

  //----------------------------------------GET HTTP Request
  if (httpResponseCode == 200) { //initialize payload if GET data is available
    Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
    payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Payload: ");
    Serial.print(payload);
    Serial.println("");
  }
  else {                      //error if no GET data 
    Serial.print("Error code: ");
    Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
  }
  // Free resources
  http.end();

  return payload;
  //----------------------------------------
}
```

Compiling this with all necessary connection details appended I get this error:

Exit status 1
Error compiling for board esp32 Dev Module

Comment: Hi ochieno Eliud, welcome to SO. The error message at the end leaves out all the relevant details from the compiler such as what exactly went wrong and on which line :)

Comment: Hi Tarmo. Thank you for your response. This below is the error part with compilation failure

Comment: Otherwise, I managed to get around the issue by commenting out this called library `#include <ESP_WiFiManager.h>` and it worked although I clearly didn't understand why.